# When/How to use таков

Tags: значения, словоупотребление, узус

From time to time I encounter the word *[таков](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=%F2%E0%EA%EE%E2&l1=1)* (in written language) but do not have a real clue about it.

Usually I replace it (mentally) with *такой* cause it's typically translated as *such*.

- In which sense *таков* is usually used?

  - Is it linked with or can it be replaced by *такой*?
  - Would there be a use case in spoken language?
- Is the female ending pronounced or not? [Wikislovar](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) and [gramota](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F2%E0%EA%EE%E2&all=x) are discordant about it.

Comment: See http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1050534

Comment: It certainly is used in spoken language, maybe in somewhat more formal settings, but nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ТАКОВ is a short form of ТАКОВОЙ, which generally means such, the same, above-mentioned.
Now answering your questions specifically

1. The main meaning is "such" that might be used as a name-replacement in a bureaucratic documentation, although in a full form ТАКОВОЙ, ТАКОВЫЕ: "К протоколу прилагаются их объяснения и замечания, если ТАКОВЫЕ имеются." - ... if such are available.
2. In the previous meaning - yes, fully. Using ТАКОВОЙ makes the sentence much more formal.
3. As to the spoken language, there are a couple of idioms with ТАКОВ. "...И был ТАКОВ" = скрылся, убежал (иронически) - in case someone did or said something and then suddenly disappeared. "Каков поп, таков приход" = everyone gets what it is worth of. The last frequent case I can think of is a statement of the type "ТАКОВ ...": "ТАКОВА судьба" - such is our destiny, "ТАКОВ человек" - such is the man (human nature), "ТАКОВЫ факты" - these are the facts.
4. Sure, ТАКОВА.

Comment: so it's *таковА* or *такОва*?

Comment: @embert It's таковА.

Comment: "Каков поп, таков и приход", literally, "a parish is the same as its priest"; meaning, leaders define moral standards for the crowd. Often translated "like priest, like people" as in the Book of Hosea, but the context and meaning there is quite different.